# Popping from Laptop Speakers

Tags: 14.04, hardware

I decided to switch and stick with ubuntu 14.04 being all the other linux distro's I've tried had various issues with the hardware of my computer. I'm using a 5 year old dell studio 1555. I'm still a bit of a linux newbie but I could use some help on fixing this problem. I saw in one thread to disable my microphone which I tried but the speakers still pop. Is there any commands or file changes I can try that would help? It's not that bad but at random intervals with music playing i'll hear a random click or two. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by popping of speakers can you speak more technically??

Comment: Basically when I play music or any audio the speaker makes sort of cracking noise at random points in a song lets say. The thing is it's not when it hits a high pitch or anythin. I'm trying basically figure if it's my hardware from maybe a point when it playing to loud or if it's something that is software related.

Comment: it might be software related or hardware related if you are having same problem on different platforms (os) then this is hardware problem ...did you try it with windows??

Comment: I didn't have this problem with windows and with other Linux distros such as Mint. When I had 12.04 I didn't have this problem. I tried going on another thread and following what one person had about turning off the power save to the speakers but when I tried save the config files it wouldn't let me.

Comment: this is problem is due to  14.04 please have a system update by sudo apt-get update

Comment: It seems to have gone away for now. If it happens again are there any terminal commands I should try?

Comment: did this happened due to update?? and there are no commands for controlling such behaviour of speakers..

Comment: Yeah because of the update the popping noise went away. As for the initial problem I have no idea. Like I said I'm still a newbie with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

try updating the system by

sudo apt-get upgrade or use Software updater/Software manager

the updates replace every bug found in the system by clean program and you get the secure and bug free enviroment. I recommend checking updates for every 8-10 days, so that your system remains bug free